# Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper::GetPathToStandardLibraries(MonoAndroid) - How to solve this?

Tags: c#, android, ios, mono

After installing Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6. Preview, I'm not able to create Cross Platform project. Every single time, I'm getting error from the picture. Any solution for this?

[image]

Comment: It is preview. Use it at your own risk. Go back to the stable release.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a bug of **Xamarin Visual Studio Template**, see [bugzilla 60995](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60995), a temporary workaround is provided for this bug:

> **Workaround**:
>   Apparently when the template is generated it'll add the following line in the android csproj file:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>"v8.0"</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

> The solution then is to change it to:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v8.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

> Without the quotes and after that, everything works fine again!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem @FrankWang, but now there is another problem after creating every single Cross Platform project, there is an error:
"The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context."